# Why doesn't my script execute after ScummVM closes?

Tags: autohotkey

My script does work up to the point where the while loop exists. ScummVM launches correctly.

However, what I want the script to do is continue to run and execute a command when it detects that scummvm.exe has closed. Every time I close scummvm, nothing happens.

```
#NoTrayIcon
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

RunWait, "..\sc55 scummvm.exe"
Run, ".\scummvm.exe" "--no-console" "--config=.\scummvm.ini" "samnmax"
Process, Exist, scummvm.exe ;wait until scummvm.exe is found before continuing
ScummVM = %ErrorLevel%  ; Save the value immediately since ErrorLevel is often changed.
while ScummVM != 0 ;while scummvm is running i.e., error level is not equal to 0
{} ;"do nothing"
msgbox "scummvm has closed" ;action taken when scummvm is closed
return
```

Answer (score 1):

**Executes a command after scummvm.exe exits**

```
RunWait, "..\sc55 scummvm.exe"
Run, ".\scummvm.exe" "--no-console" "--config=.\scummvm.ini" "samnmax"
loop {
  sleep 5000    ; 5 seconds
  Process, Exist, scummvm.exe
} until ErrorLevel == 0
msgbox "scummvm has closed"
return
```